# Elliptic regularity of harmonic forms in $L^1$

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

$\newcommand{\M}{M}$
Let $\M$ be a smooth oriented Riemannian manifold.

Let $\sigma$ be a differential $k$-form on $\M$ with coefficients in $L^1(\M)$.  We say $\sigma$ is weakly harmonic if 
$$
\int_{\M} \langle \sigma , \Delta \alpha \rangle=0 \, \text{ for every smooth compactly supported $\alpha \in \Omega^{k}(\M)$}. 
 $$

**Theorem:** Weakly harmonic forms (in $L^1$) are smooth.

I know a reference to this theorem, when we assume $\sigma \in L^2$ instead of $L^1$. **I am looking for a reference which deals with the $L^1$ case, which naively looks harder.**

(Or, if possible, for an easy way to reduce the $L^1$ theorem to the $L^2$ theorem).

If that matters, I don't really care about global topology here, i.e. we can assume $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ topologically. (but not "Riemannialy trivial", that is, I don't assume the metric is Euclidean).

---

In my case, I actually know that $\sigma \in L^1$ is weakly closed and weakly co-closed (which is stronger than being weakly harmonic, if $M$ is not closed)
, but I am not sure it matters. For completeness, these are the definitions I am using for these properties:

$$
 \text{ weakly closed if } \,  \int_{\M} \langle \sigma, \delta \alpha \rangle =0 \, \text{ for every compactly supported $\alpha \in \Omega^{k+1}(\M)$}, 
$$

$$
\text{ weakly co-closed if } \, \int_{\M} \langle \sigma ,d \alpha \rangle=0 \, \text{ for every compactly supported $\alpha \in \Omega^{k-1}(\M)$}, 
$$

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: Oh, you're right. I misread his statement. I'll delete the comment.

Comment: @JackLee Actually, I agree with you that my original phrasing was a bit misleading, so I changed it. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I asked this question on MO. An answer is given [here][1]. [1]:https://mathoverflow.net/a/309335/46290